# Как сбиндить свойство DisplayMember внутри Datatemplate?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть девэкспрессовский контрол `ListBoxEdit`. У него установлено свойство `DisplayMember="Naimenovanie"`. Это значит, что из объекта берется для отображения свойство "Naimenovanie". А теперь вопрос. Я переопределил `ItemTemplate`

```
<dxe:ListBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Naimenovanie}">
            <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding Command="{x:Static local:WndCatalogCommands.LoadBranchCommand}" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick"/>
            </TextBlock.InputBindings>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</dxe:ListBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
```

Что мне нужно написать в свойстве `Text` вместо `{Binding Naimenovanie}`, чтобы подтягивалось значение свойства, указанного в `DisplayMember`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, таким путём пойти не удастся.

В стоковом WPF `DisplayMemberPath` в `ItemsControl`'е [устанавливает `ItemTemplateSelector`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,398), и является таким образом «быстрым шаблоном».
Так что либо вы пользуетесь кастомным шаблоном, и прописываете там нужный `Binding`, либо пользуетесь `DisplayMemberPath`, и шаблон за вас берётся из WPF.

Скорее всего, в DevExpress'овских контролах используется та же стратегия для совместимости со стоковым WPF. (Но я не могу перепроверить, у меня нет их dll для декомпиляции.)